# install mathematica 9 on linux encounter "Glibc_2.4" not found

Tags: installation

I tried install mathematica 9 on linux. The whole process is fine. After the installation. I type "mathematica", and came up following lines:

> /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica: /lib64/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libML64i3.so)
>
> /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica: /lib64/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libQtCore.so.4)

It seems that I need to update my Glibc. But I received warnings that update Gilbc is highly risky. What should I do? How to update Glibc safely??

Or should I return to low edition mathematica? my Glibc version is glibc-2.3.4-2.39. Which edition of mathematica can I install?

Comment: which Linux exactly?

Comment: @RolfMertig Description:Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 6)

Comment: @RolfMertig Linux 2.6.9-67

Comment: @user15964 Can you [join the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RedHat 4 is not a supported Linux platform--either by us, or by even by Red Hat.  Your safest course of action is to upgrade to a newer Red Hat version (the current is 6.3, but any 5.x is supported), or to stick with Mathematica 8.  Upgrading glibc by itself is certainly possible, but not entirely straightforward (you would need to find an RPM which is newer but doesn't depend on thing else new being installed, or compile from source yourself), and this may effect the warranty/support contract you have with Red Hat.