# Running latex via `RunProcess` or `ExternalEvaluate` fails in Ubuntu 18.04 due to `ZLIB_ 1.2.9' not found

Tags: linux, external-calls

I want to compile some latex documents programmatically. But one error is spoiling my whole pipeline that works in Windows.

### **How to reproduce:**

Install `texlive` on Ubuntu 18.04 where MMA 11.3 is already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
which xelatex
```

> /usr/bin/xelatex

Now the `xelatex`command works fine on terminal. But when one tries to run it from MMA it fails with a library incompatibility issue.

We can see mathematica forcing dependency.

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "ldd /usr/bin/xelatex"]
```

The `StandardOutput` of `RunProcess` shows the error. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wnHUMgN2) of the whole output.

> /usr/bin/xelatex: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
>       linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc36b7000)

Similar question here: [18653](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18653/install-mathematica-9-on-linux-encounter-glibc-2-4-not-found)

Same error comes when I tried using Python/Node via `ExternalEvaluate`. Here iare the specific examples.

#### Node.js

```
session = StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "NodeJS",
"SessionProlog" -> "const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;"|>];
ExternalEvaluate[session,"code = execSync('xelatex');"]["data"]
// ByteArray // ByteArrayToString
```

#### Python

```
session = StartExternalSession[<|"System" -> "Python", "Version" -> "3.6", 
"SessionProlog" -> "from subprocess import PIPE, run"|>];
fac = "command = ['ls','-a']
result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
  print(result.returncode, result.stdout, result.stderr)";
ExternalEvaluate[session, fac]
```

Try `pwd` or `ls -a` in place of `xelatex` everything will work fine and we will see the shell output as we see in an ordinary terminal.

1. I have tried copying the `libz.so.1` from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64` but that brings some symbol error but the `'ZLIB_1.2.9' not found` error vanishes.
2. I tried installing [arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara) (install arara : `sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils`) to replace ghe usage of `xelatex` command in my program with `arara`. Same problem came back when calling `arara` from `RunProcess`, though Ubuntu terminal worked fine.

Without this piece of latex automation I can't port my code in Ubuntu 18.04 (one of the most popular Linux dist). It will be interesting to know if this above nightmare happens also on Ubuntu 16.04.

## Update

Based on the great comment `xelatex` could be **brought to work**.

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "/usr/bin/xelatex "<>texFile<>".tex 
exit", ProcessEnvironment -> <|"libz.so.1" -> "/usr/lib64/libz.so.1"|>]
```

#### General solution/rule of thumb?

How to solve those above `StartExternalSession` and `ExternalEvaluate`?

Also some other commands that work on terminal fails for example the latex automation tool `arara`. When trying `arara` in the following it gives another error.

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell,All,"arara "<>texFile<>".tex"
ProcessEnvironment-><|"libz.so.1"->"/usr/lib64/libz.so.1"|>]
```

> <|ExitCode->1,StandardOutput->,StandardError->lstat(./kpsewhich) failed ...
>   ./kpsewhich: No such file or directory
>   kpsewhich: ../../../texk/kpathsea/progname.c:316: remove_dots: Assertion `ret' failed.
>   Error: Unable to access jarfile 
>   |>

I could solve the above error  by using

```
ProcessEnvironment->
<|"libz.so.1"->"/usr/lib64/libz.so.1","PATH" -> Environment["PATH"]|>
```

What is the general method to handle this kind of issues and how to fix the `StartExternalSession`, is there any analog of `ProcessEnvironment` there ?

Comment: Does `RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "ldd /usr/bin/xelatex", 
 ProcessEnvironment -> <|"libz.so.1" -> "/usr/lib64/libz.so.1"|>]` help ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks nice it does help in the above command. Can you make this an answer please. Also any idea how the same process environment trick can be done for r `ExternalEvaluate`? I have added `ExternalEvaluate` example code for both Node and Python. Also I failed to run `arara` via RunProcess using this trick. But managed to get `xelatex` working. Thx a lot!!

Comment: Let's see if there are more comprehensive answers.